# Comparing two Lists using Zip function in Python

Tags: python, list, sum, zip, increment

I am comparing two lists together and if they match I want to increment a counter. 
Right now the counter is saying 0 each time I print it out even though there should be some matches. Both lists have data within them as well because I can print them out. Below is the code that I am using to find a match in the lists and increment if they do match. What could be going wrong?

```
numCorrect = sum(1 for a, b in zip(trueLabels, predLabels) if a == b)
```

Any advice helps, Thanks

Comment: Working fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works well:

```
trueLabels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
predLabels = [1, 2, 4, 4, 5]

numCorrect = sum(1 for a, b in zip(trueLabels, predLabels) if a == b)
print(numCorrect)
# 4
```

You may have shifted indices in your list(s).